# Prevent refresh caused by dropdown in JavaScript add-in for PowerPoint

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins

I'm developing and Office add-in project for PowerPoint where users can receive videos that are dinamically added to the add-in when users request it.

I've followed the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/powerpoint-quickstart?tabs=visual-studio) and everything is working, the problem is that I have a dropdown as follows:

```html
<select id="dropdown-countries">
    <option value="value">Country</option>
 <option value="value">Country</option>
    <option value="value">Country</option>
</select>
```

When the user requests a video everything works normally and the video appears as intended, however, when putting PowerPoint in presentation mode, if the user has changed the value of Dropdown, the entire add-in is loaded again and all the information (the video and the option chosen in the dropdown) is lost, otherwise the content of the add-in, like the video, remains the same.

When I change the dropdown the VS gives the following warning:

```
DOM7011: The code on this page has disabled intermittent caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
```

What I want is for the video to remain in the add-in even when PowerPoint is put into presentation mode. I can't use localstorage to keep info because users can have multiple instances of my add-in on the same slide and throughout the presentation.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How are you saving your page/app's state?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I do not think I'm doing that.
I thought of saving the page information with the localstorage, but as I explained, when users have different instances of the addin on the same slide and throughout the document I think it is not possible to register the information for each of these instances. However I may be wrong, hence my request for help too :)

Comment: In the end, these add-ins are just a web app running within a sandboxed browser session. If you're not storing the state, any time the page refreshes it will reset back to the default value. You need to use some mechanism (cookies, URI fragments, backend session cache, etc.) to capture the current value and restore it when the page refreshes.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Thanks, it was exactly that, I explored these mechanisms better and I solved the problem by saving the information I wanted to reuse after the refresh using SessionStorage.